# How can I pass multiple parameters to Actionlink() while working with entity framework on c#/html

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework

In my project i am working with MVC design and using the database with Entity Framework.
I wanted to update some cells in my database, but I am not sure how to pass them to the controller to update.

On the Update View page, the user can change the content of the cells using

```html
<td>
    <div contenteditable>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.HeadLine)
</td>
```

But when I try to send the updated data to the controller I can only understand how to send an id for the Model(because I cannot pass the Model itself).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong - here I am trying to pass an ID so the controller would know what to change and the new name - I get a compilation error.

```html
<p>
    @Html.Action("Update This Post >>", "Update", new { param1 = Model.ID, param2 = Model.Author });
</p>
```

The controller signature is :

```html
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(int id, string author)
```

Comment: Why can you not post the Model?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Update This Post >>","YourController", "Update", new { id = Model.ID, author = Model.Author });
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This eventually solved the problem - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are trying to pass a reference type or value type variables in the action. you should not pass the reference type but the value types for the anonymous object to pass route parameters. Can you try the below code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update This Post >>", "Update", new { id= Model.ID, author= Model.Author });
```